# @font-font issue with fontawesome

Tags: php, css, font-awesome

I am having issues with my fontawesome …

**font-awesome.css**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype'), 
  url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

the issue is that my icons are not loading I have try `www.example/com/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot` and the file get downloaded which means that the link works

in my **head.php** file I am calling `font-awesome.css` which is in my css folder like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $directories->fetchdir($css); ?>/font-awesome.css">
```

this is the same way I am calling all my js and image folder and this works fine.

in my **index.php** file I am calling the head.php like this

```
<?php include_once ("views/head.php"); ?>
```

The reason why I am showing all this is because might this be a reason why my `fontawesome-webfont.eot are not showing? or is it another reason?

[image]

Please help

Comment: Unless the path to the CSS resource that you are dynamically generating is wrong, this has nothing to do with PHP. Have you checked whether or not that resource gets loaded correctly using the net panel in your browser’s developer tools?

Comment: Use the web developer tool with chrome to see if the ressources are loaded

Comment: @CBroe @soyuka the source does get loading. In developer tool this is what I see `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.local/css//font-awesome.css">` when I click on it. it open up the css file. which means its loaded

Comment: Have you set the mime-types for the fonts on your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardcode your fontawesome URL to test if it works?
If it works, then try to remove ".." from css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
  src: url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'), 
  url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype'), 
  url('/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

You'll have to work on the rendered mark-up and then fix your fontawesome path:
It will be helpful to see where is your CSS relevant to your "/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot" down-loadable file.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. i tried `(fonts/...)` but thought i tried `(/fonts/...)`.